# Problems in jquery function after running a javascript and change elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two codes. first one is for an autocomplete and 2nd one is to add rows to a table.\
In the table i have add two rows in default. and autosuggest function works in that case. But after running the JavaScript which adds rows to the table that autosuggest jquery is not working. I checked many posts. As I figured the problem is with the ready function. How to correct it?

**Code - 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#tag1").autocomplete({
                    source:'getautocomplete.php',
                    minLength:1
                });
            });
    </script>
```

**Code -2**

```
<script language="javascript">
    var i = 2;
    function changeIt(){
        var myCurrentTable = document.getElementById("foodadd");
        var txt = myCurrentTable.innerHTML;
        i++;
        if(i<=5){
        txt = txt.replace('<tr id="etc_row">', '</tr><tr id="url_row_' + i + '"><td>Food Name </strong></td><td>: </td><td align="right"><input name="tag' + i + '" id="tag'+i+'" type="text" size="40" required="required" /></td><tr id="etc_row">');
        myCurrentTable.innerHTML = txt;
    }}
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you mean `$(document).ready`?

Comment: yes. It is not working after the javascript is executed to add a row.

Comment: My mistake. It should be "$(document).ready"

Comment: @user3000716 I am confused. Did this answer your question? If so elclanrs should post it as an answer and you should accept it. Get it off the unanswered questions list.

Comment: In your example code you're calling autocomplete on `#tag1`.  In your function to add a row, you're giving the `td` an id not less than 2 or more than 5 - do you account for this in your live code? If not, that's your issue.  You should add a class to every `td` that needs autocomplete functionality, and then call it with `$('.myClass').autocomplete();`.  Additionally, since these are added elements, there may be an issue with autocomplete binding to the new `td` elements, but you'll need to solve this before encountering that.

Comment: Actually I'm having a problem with binding new elements with autocomplete. Because in the complete code I have these lines as well.

Comment: You call autocomplete on #tag1, #tag2, #tag3, #tag4, and #tag5?  If so, I hope this helps you see how extraneous that is.

Comment: <table id="foodadd">
    <tr>
        <td >Food Name </td><td>:</td>
        <td><input name="tag1"  id="tag1"type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Food Name </td><td>:</td>
        <td ><input name="tag2" id="tag2"type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="etc_row">
        <td ></td>
        <td></td><td></td> </tr>
        
        
        
        
       
    <tr id="url_row_1" >
      <td></td><td></td>
      <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Compare Foods" /><button onClick="javascript:changeIt();"><b>+</b></button></td>
    </tr>
     
    
    
</table>

Comment: OK. I'll try to explain this better:  when you write `('#tag1').autocomplete()` you are saying, "Hey, autocomplete, watch anything that has `id=tag1` and do your thing".  Now, when you add new rows and cells, you are giving those cells `id=tag2`, `id=tag3` and so on.  Autocomplete doesn't care about those cells, because you haven't told it to care about them.  Make sense?

Comment: Yes. So how can I bind new elements with that autocomplete jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `autocomplete()` on a class selector, instead of an id.  Then add the class `autocompleteMe` to your original markup (the HTML that contains your starting cells that do have the id `tag1`.  Notice that I also added `class=autocompleteMe` to your `changeIt` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".autocompleteMe").autocomplete({
    source:'getautocomplete.php',
    minLength:1
  });
});
var i = 2;

function changeIt(){
    var myCurrentTable = document.getElementById("foodadd");
    var txt = myCurrentTable.innerHTML;
    i++;
    if(i<=5){
    txt = txt.replace('<tr id="etc_row">', '</tr><tr id="url_row_' + i + '"><td>Food Name </strong></td><td>: </td><td align="right"><input class="autocompleteMe" name="tag' + i + '" id="tag'+i+'" type="text" size="40" required="required" /></td><tr id="etc_row">');
    myCurrentTable.innerHTML = txt;
}}
```